# Search for Gmail messages received on a particular date

Tags: gmail

I want to search for Gmail messages received on a particular date.

I can find messages received *before* YYYY/MM/DD using:

```
Before:YYYY/MM/DD
```

I can find messages received *after* YYYY/MM/DD using:

```
After:YYYY/MM/DD
```

But how can I find messages received *after* one date but *before* another date?  The following search seems to find messages received on 2021/07/01 *and* on 2021/06/30:

```
Before:2021/07/02 After:2021/06/30
```

How do I find only messages received on 2021/07/01?

Comment: Have you tried `After:2021/06/30 Before:2021/07/02`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

```
 after:2021/07/01 before:2021/07/02
```

I used the assumption that the time of day used was midnight.

So I was asking for everything between July 1st 2021 00:00:00 but before July 2nd 2021 00:00:00

Comment: that is the correct answer.